# How to make a fade in effect when loading images (when I scroll)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

If I load 20 images, I would like to load them with a fade in effect only if the user scrolls down.

Heres the code :

```
<?php
//Proceso de conexión con la base de datos
$conex = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")
        or die("No se pudo realizar la conexion");
    mysql_select_db("sesiones_php",$conex)
        or die("ERROR con la base de datos");

//Iniciar Sesión
session_start();

//Validar si se está ingresando con sesión correctamente
if (!$_SESSION){
echo '<script language = javascript>
alert("usuario no autenticado")
self.location = "login.php"
</script>';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar Examples</title>

<!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<!-- Main stylesheet imports bootstrap css and adds custom -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        /* To keep short panes open decently tall */
        .tab-pane {min-height: 500px;}
    </style>

<!-- Modernizr for browser feature-checking 
            + HTML5shiv (included in modernizr) see modernizr.com -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <!-- alternatively, remove these lines and place icons
                directly in the site parent folder 
                mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="brand" href="members.php">Divagueando</a>
              <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li><a href="members.php"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Inicio</a></li>
                  <li><a href="bandeja.php">Mensajes Privados</a></li>
                  <li><a href="inbox.php">Nuevo Mensaje</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="galeria.php">Ver todas las fotos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="fotoperfil.php">Foto perfil</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="configuracion.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></a>
              </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
          </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /navbar -->



        <div class="container">

        <div class="contenedorfoto">


        <?php 
        $conexion=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die('No hay conexión a la base de datos');
        $db=mysql_select_db('carpe',$conexion)or die('no existe la base de datos.');


        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $consulta=mysql_query("select * from datos where idUsuario='".$id."' order by id desc");
        while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
            $ruta=$filas['ruta'];
            $desc=$filas['descripcion'];


        ?>

        <?php echo $desc;?><br>
        <img src="imagenperfil/<?php echo $ruta; ?>" width="200" height="300"><br>
        <hr>
        <?php }?>




        </div>

      <footer>
        <p>By David Cochran of <a href="http://okwu.edu">Oklahoma Wesleyan University</a> and <a href="http://alittlecode.com/">aLittleCode.com</a> for <a href="http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/">webdesign.tutsplus.com</a>. Free for your use! (No warranties, no guarantees.)</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

<!-- ==============================================
         JavaScript below!                                                          -->

<!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS: compiled and minified -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Example plugin: Prettify -->
    <script src="js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Scripts -->
        <script>
            // Activate Google Prettify in this page
            addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);

            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Add prettyprint class to pre elements
                    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint');

                // Initialize tabs and pills
                    $('.note-tabs').tab();

            }); // end document.ready
        </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I retrieve all the images for one user and display them. I would like to show them with the fade in effect, when he scrolls.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, if I disable javascript on my browser, `self.location = "login.php"` will be ignored and the rest of your page will be printed

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the [Lazy Load plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to delay the loading of image data until they are visible. The plugin site has an [example with the fadeIn effect](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Load is an option but that would delay loading. Another option is to use the [jQuery inview event](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/) plugin, which may better deliver the effect you seek. It depends on exactly what you want.

With *jQuery inview*, the code would be as follows :

```
$(function(){
    $('img.fadeMe').css('opacity', 0).one('inview', function(event, visible) {
      if(visible) {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    });
    window.trigger('scroll');//fadeIn images at top of page that are initially in view.
});
```

*untested*

With this approach, images are allowed to load in the normal way, having been pre-styled with `'opacity', 0` to make them initially invisible. Thus, there's a good chance of zero delay before each image having been loaded before it's faded in as it comes into view.

With Lazy Load, you are guaranteed a loading delay before images becomes available - that's what Lazy Load does.

Try both approaches and see which best suites your site.